# How to put utf-8 text to input field Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, chat

I building a app chat, and I come from  Vietnam. But Input field in Unity dont show  Vietnamese text. How I can get text from Input field is utf-8 text.
 I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm sorry for every mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I believe GUI in Unity uses UTF-16 and not UTF-8.  You should be able to encode your file with UTF-16 in Monodevelop.

Comment: Thank for answer, In fact, I building a Chatbot, that get input in the Input field and compare with clause in xml file (utf-8) and show clause output. And when I use UTF-16 in xml file,  doc.Load(filename); have error.